# Helm wait till dependency deployment are ready on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dependencies, devops, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-deployment

I'm using helm chart to deploy my application on kubernetes. But services that I'm using in my stack depends on other services how do I make sure helm will not deploy until the dependencies are up?

Answer (score 10):

Typically you don't; you just let Helm (or `kubectl apply -f`) start everything in one shot and let it retry starting everything.

The most common pattern is for a container process to simply crash at startup if an external service isn't available; the Kubernetes Pod mechanism will restart the container when this happens.  If the dependency never comes up you'll be stuck in CrashLoopBackOff state forever, but if it appears in 5-10 seconds then everything will come up normally within a minute or two.

Also remember that pods of any sort are fairly disposable in Kubernetes.  IME if something isn't working in a service one of the first things to try is `kubectl delete pod` and letting a Deployment controller recreate it.  Kubernetes can do this on its own too, for example if it decides it needs to relocate a pod on to a different node.  That is: even if some dependency is up when your pod first start sup, there's no guarantee it will stay up forever.

Comment: HI, we need the same functionality with helm, I mean chart B that will deployed just after chart A is installed and up and running, similar to `wait` command. after few years, there is better solution?

Comment: This setup hasn't changed.  The last paragraph is still relevant: the application B still needs some way to react if application A fails after startup time, and that's not really a different situation from A not being ready yet.