# Is there any way with HELM to ordering pods deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm currently deploying a product with 15 JAVA Spring micro services which all depend on one micro service (we will call it "first-service") which is needed by the others to work.

The thing is that as long as the first-service is not ready, all others can't start and will try restarting, resulting in a excessive CPU consumption.

This will make first-service to take a lot of time to be up and so others app will also take a lot of time.

So my question is : **is it possible to indicate to HELM to deploy "first-service" before all others and wait until config-service is ready ?**

Thanks,

Comment: Can you `helm install --wait` the first service, then `helm install` the others?  In [Helm wait till dependency deployment are ready on kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54928861/helm-wait-till-dependency-deployment-are-ready-on-kubernetes) I note there isn't a path to do this in an "umbrella" chart, and IME the easiest and most common approach is in fact to let the dependent services restart.  (Also I've had some bad experiences with "umbrella" charts; I believe tools like Helmfile can do this though.)

Answer (score 0):

Build a separate helm for "first-service" and make the others depends on it:

https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/

Answer (score 0):

If your services are being deployed with a **single** helm chart, then I would advise to use an [helm hook](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) like `pre-upgrade`/`pre-install`. You can that specify your first service to be deployed before the others.

If your services are in different helm chart, usually it requires some kind of deployment orchestration, so depending on how you deploy your apps you could:

- With [ArgoCD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), use [sync-waves](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves/) to order Applications deployment.
- With [FluxCD](https://fluxcd.io/), you can order your Kustomizations with [dependsOn](https://fluxcd.io/flux/components/kustomize/kustomizations/#dependencies)
- With standard helm deployments (I could imagine a standard CI/CD pipeline), you would start to deploy first-service helm chart, and add the [`--wait` flag](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-installupgraderollback) to make sure the app is ready before passing to the next deployment.